# Why can't I free dynamic memory?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, destructor

**EDIT**

Found the answer. It's a logical error located at

```
if(carry == 0 && index < 0)
    exit = true;
```

Since each segment starts with 18 digits (hence the `index = 17;` right before the while loop), when shift has a value less than that the code will keep writing beyond the `answer[0]`. I have fixed it by adding an additional condition to trip the exit flag.

Sorry for the confusion.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

Here's a function I wrote to multiply two integers in the format of char arrays with each cell representing a single decimal number (eg. 1234 would be "1234+").

```
char* multichar(char* one, char* two)
{
    // one has m digits, two has n digits
    int m = char_size(one) - 1;
    int n = char_size(two) - 1;
    int m_seg = m / 9 + 1;
    int n_seg = n / 9 + 1;
    int m_head = m % 9;
    int n_head = n % 9;
    int index, shift;
    bool exit = false, m_flag = true, n_flag = true;
    _int64 product, alpha, bravo;
    char carry = 0, sum;
    char temp[18];
    char* answer = new char[m + n + 1];
    memset(answer, 0, m + n + 1);
    if(m_head == 0)
    {
        m_seg--;
        m_flag = false;
    }
    if(n_head == 0)
    {
        n_seg--;
        n_flag = false;
    }

    for(int i = n_seg - 1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        for(int j = m_seg - 1; j > -1; j--)
        {
            shift = m + n - (m_seg + n_seg - i - j) * 9 + 17;
            if(i == 0 && n_head != 0)
                bravo = segtoint(two, 0, n_head);
            else
                bravo = segtoint(two, n_head + (i - n_flag) * 9, 9);
            if(j == 0 && m_head != 0)
                alpha = segtoint(one, 0, m_head);
            else
                alpha = segtoint(one, m_head + (j - m_flag) * 9, 9);

            product = alpha * bravo;
            if(product == 0)
                memset(temp, 0, 18);
            else
            {
                for(int k = 17; k > -1; k--)
                {
                    temp[k] = product % 10;
                    product /= 10;
                }
            }
            // add temp to answer from index backwards;
            index = 17;
            exit = false;
            while(!exit)
            {
                if(index < 0)
                    sum = answer[shift] + carry;
                else
                    sum = answer[shift] + temp[index] + carry;
                carry = sum / 10;
                answer[shift] = sum % 10;
                index--;
                shift--;
                if(carry == 0 && index < 0)
                    exit = true;
            }
        }
    }
    answer[m + n] = one[m] == two[n]? '+':'-';

    return answer;
}
```

In my `int main()` I put

```
char* omega = multichar(delta, echo);
delete[] omega;
return 0;
```

But that results in a `BLOCK IS VALID` error... Why can't I delete the pointer?

Comment: Use valgrind. Most likely you overwrote something.

Comment: Could it be that you are going out of some array boundaries somewhere, therefore going over `answer` and corrupting it?

Comment: part from the 'new' and 'delete' your code is very much C. You would spare yourself some headache by using more C++ constructs e.g. string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your size calculations are off. For example, for `char_size(one) == 1` and `char_size(one) == 1` you get `m = n = 0` and `m_seg = n_seg = 1`. Then in the first iteration of the loops you have `i = 0` and `j = 0` and from that:

```
shift = 0 + 0 - (1 + 1 - 0 - 0) * 9 + 17;
```

That is `shift = -1`. Later in that loop you write to `answer[shift]`, which will be out of bounds of the array.

Comment: No, m & n are never zero. The `char_size(one) - 1` is to get rid of the sentinel (ie. '+', '-') at the end. A single digit number would have m value of 1. P.S. Wut your name is sth like mine LOL

Answer (score 2):

At the very least, there is heap corruption caused by the fact that `shift` is never initialised. Your code writes to `answer[shift]` and this will be where the heap corruption occurs.

I would expect your compiler to be warning about this. I've not checked the code carefully and would not be surprised if there were more errors.

---

**Update:** The answer above was written to go with the original question that indeed did not initialise `shift`. The updated code shows how `shift` is initialised but still omits vital parts of code. No matter, my conclusion is the same. You will have a heap corruption somewhere due to `shift` being out of bounds at some point in your loop that writes to `answer`. Simply add some diagnostics output, or use a debugger, to inspect `shift` and I'm sure the problem will become clear.

Comment: I didn't post the entire function. Shift is initialized in the segments missing from the above code. You know what, let me post the whole thing...

Comment: @sth128:How can you expect people to tell you what is wrong with your code unless you post your **real** code?

Comment: +1. I'm guessing that `shift` is (by chance) starting out as zero, so each occurrence of `--shift` and subsequent assignment to `answer[shift]` is overwriting the area where the allocator keeps track of what's in the allocated block.

Comment: Are you serious. You post some random code and ask why some other code fails?

Comment: @David Helferman: Random code? The function returns a character pointer. When I call the function, it makes a new char pointer. In order to not have memory leaks, I need to kill it. I don't see how my codes are "random".

Comment: I mean that you didn't post the code that you are really running. All the same I bet shift is out of range at some point. You can debug it easily enough. It's hard for us because even now you have not supplied enough code for us to diagnose.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm unsure which "vital" part of my code is missing (I only called one external function `char_size` which returns the size of the array as an integer) but the problem was indeed traced to `shift`.